# Пременная передаваемая в другой процесс

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, threading

Есть два файла main.py и imported.py . Функция imported.py используется во втором потоке, и содержит код вида:

```
while not stop:
    тут код
```

Сама же переменная stop находится в main.py и динамически меняется. Как я могу отслеживать эту перемнную, при условии что код точно должен быть в двух разных файлах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передайте Event через функцию. Аргументом при создании треда.